# parse JSON working on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, symfony

I know there is much questions about json, but they don't answer my question (or I couldn't find anything, that would help me).
Part of my Symfony2 controller that sends me data.

```
return $this->createResponse(array(
            'result' => $users
    ));
die();
}
/**
 * Interni pomocna funkce na vytvareni json odpovedi
 * @param unknown $array
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function createResponse($array = array()) {
return new Response(
        json_encode($array),
        200,
        array(
                        header('Content-type: application/json')    
        )
);
}
```

Javascript function that gets JSON data.

```
function getUsers(date_from, date_to) {
alert(date_from+" "+date_to);
var url = "{{ path('vetkomdochazkaBundle_apiGetUsers') }}";
$.post(url, JSON.stringify([date_from,date_to]), function(data) {
           markUsers(data['result']);
            }, 'json');
};
```

Everything works fine on localhost (wamp server), I gets data and parse it so I can use it as array. But when I run it on php5.3 server I get right data (I can write it with JSON.stringify), but I can't use them same way as on localhost (I can't use alert(data['result']), it only write object Object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `data` contain, have you done a `console.log(data);`?

Comment: console.log display same data as alert on localhost, but I changed for cyclus markUsers function and it is working now also on server.

I use for (key in users) instead of for(index = 0; index<users.length; ++index)

Comment: I know this won't help you with your problem, but since version 2.1 of Symfony, there is a class called JsonResponse. You should be able to return your response this way: return new JsonResponse($array);

Comment: The [header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) doesn't return anything. Your `array(header('Content-type: application/json'))` is most likely wrong.

Comment: @Alvaro: you are right, that's definitely his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP VERSION JSON FUNCTION IS PHP 5 >= 5.2.0,

Comment: the OP said he was using PHP 5.3 on his server.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has a `JsonResponse` object that might make your code a little cleaner, and could fix your problem. Also, take out the die

```
/**
 * Interni pomocna funkce na vytvareni json odpovedi
 * @param unknown $array
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
protected function createResponse($array = array()) {
    return new JsonResponse(
        $array,
        200
    );
}
```

otherwise, you need to set headers, like so

```
return new Response(
    json_encode($array),
    200,
    array('Content-type', 'application/json')
);
```